# How do i Flip a regex?

Tags: php, regex, pcre

i am using the following regex to check input for anyting other then the allowed characters...(a-zA-z0-9 a dot, comma, dash and a singlequote and the br tag)

```
<?php

$regex_char_appearance = '/([A-Za-z0-9 \-\.\,\']|(<br>))/';

?>
```

I have been trying to create a regex to clean user input. I just can't get it to work so tried different things like...

```
<?php

    $regex_char_appearance = '/(?!<br>)([^A-Za-z0-9 \-\.\,\'])/';

    $regex_char_appearance = '/([^A-Za-z0-9 \-\.\,\']|[^(<br>)])/';

   //remove anything other then alphabetic and allowed
    $post_char_appearance = preg_replace( $regex_char_appearance , '' , $post_char_appearance);

?>
```

so the goal is to remove anything other then a-zA-z0-9, a dot, comma, dash , singlequote and the br tag for output with preg_replace.

Can someone help me put a regex together that works?

Comment: I guess `[^A-Za-z0-9.,'-]` should be enough for the *remove anything other then a-zA-**Z**0-9, a dot, comma, dash and a singlequote* requirement. What is `<br>` doing here? You want to match anything other than `<br>`?

Comment: my bad....and a the <br> is allowed as well....but not < or >.

Comment: Ok, `'~[^A-Za-z0-9.,'-]~'` should work then. Doesn't it?

Comment: that would remove the <br> tag...

Comment: Ok, then just match it and restore with a backreferences: `preg_replace('~(<br\s*/?>)|[^A-Za-z0-9.,'-]~' , '$1' , $post_char_appearance);` - [demo](https://regex101.com/r/yJ0yU8/2)

Comment: nope..it doesn't leave the <br> intact...thanks for the demo...usefull!

Comment: Please post your example code proving it does not work. As you see in my demo, the `<br>` are reinserted back into string while `preg_replace`ing.

Comment: Actually...that worked! I never used a callback before but i will read into it...thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can match your disallowed characters with `[^A-Za-z0-9.,'-]` (a negated [**character class**](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php) matching any character but those defined in the class).

To keep `br` tags intact, match and capture it with a pair of unescaped parentheses (a [**grouping construct**](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php) `(...)`) and restore with a [**backreference**](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.back-references.php) `$1`:

```
$regex_char_appearance = '~(<br\s*/?>)|[^A-Za-z0-9.,'-]~';
$post_char_appearance = preg_replace($regex_char_appearance, '$1' , $post_char_appearance);
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yJ0yU8/3)

Note that `[A-z]` does not only match all ASCII letters, see more on this in [*Why is this regex allowing a caret?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771901/why-is-this-regex-allowing-a-caret/29771926#29771926)